# Failed API Request 82007 unsupported runtime: node16

Tags: node.js, git, npm, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

following the steps from: https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/call-gpt-twilio#Deploy-functions
after i put in:
npm run deploy
this error popped up:
ERROR Failed API Request 82007
│
│ unsupported runtime: node16
│
│ More info: https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/82007

I found out that twilio only supports node18: https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/faq#which-runtimes-are-available-for-twilio-functions

what should i do for me to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the used Node version in these places:

1. To use Node 18 locally, you can edit the [`.nvmrc`](https://github.com/kuschanton/call-gpt/blob/main/.nvmrc) file.

```
16
```

> This won't fix the issue but it will ensure you use the same version for deployment and local testing

2. But the error you are seeing is caused by the metadata described in [`.twilioserverlessrc`](https://github.com/kuschanton/call-gpt/blob/main/.twilioserverlessrc#L36) and [`package.json`](https://github.com/kuschanton/call-gpt/blob/1bb72a8621e49c494b5f614bd1c95826a16fdc45/package.json#L25)

```
"runtime": "node16"     /* The version of Node.js to deploy the build to. (node16) */,
```

```js
"engines": {
  "node": "16"
}
```

**Change the version to 18 in all these files and then try to redeploy.**

Comment: would you happen to know how I would implement a kind of script to this that would respond to business specific questions. i was thinking that i would make a custom gpt filled with documentation about the business and instructions on how to respond to customers calling the line but I cant find a way to take a api key of a custom gpt specifically. thanks!